# Which SRID does Apple Maps use?

Tags: iphone, dictionary, srid

The app will send the latitude and longitude to the server.
It looks like it is probably NAD83 or WGS84 and I'm confused by some of the stuff I've been reading.

Comment: what does the "Android" tag have to do with Apple Maps?

Comment: Apologies, I've removed the Android tag.  I added the tag before finalizing my question.

Comment: After some more reading, it looks like it is WGS84.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the documentation! Apple's CoreLocation uses WSG84.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationcoordinate2d

Comment: Thanks.  Couldn't find that anywhere five years ago though.

Comment: I believe that. I've been looking for this info periodically for years and could only find speculation until very recently. They must have just (finally) added it to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

This post seems to confirm that all GPS companies use WGS84.  Apple uses TOMTOM data.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/664214bb-abbc-4d14-91db-1ccfeb239371/importance-of-choosing-srid